# Is there any chapter/Scripture in Bhagavad Geeta that specifically talks about sutak (Death)

Tags: bhagavad-gita, death

For example what rules and regulations to follow when a close relative dies in the family - specifically in Bhagavad Geeta.
i know that its mentioned very well in the Garuda Purana, but i would like to know if Bhagavad Geeta covered any parts of it?

Comment: no Gita does not.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda That is an answer. can you please write that in the answer field?

Comment: @Sarvabhouma you can only 'prove' a positive. You cannot prove a negative.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda thank you, i had a friend who does not follow Sutak, his reason was because it was not mentioned in Geeta. so for General knowledge are their casts who specifically follow some holy scriptures and ignore others?